# Indexing Google Sites: "Failed: Robots.txt unreachable" error

Tags: indexing, robots.txt, google-search-console, google-sites, namecheap

I have made a simple one page website via Google Sites and have a custom domain from namecheap. My site is verified and it shows up when I put the custom URL in, but it's not appearing when I search for it on Google. I have checked my publish settings and it's public.

I have done a URL inspection via Google Search Console and it comes up with "Page cannot be indexed: Not available due to a site-wide issue".

It then states "URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met" and for Page fetch it states "Failed: Robots.txt unreachable".

Any idea what this means or how I can index my site so it shows up on search engines?

Thanks!

I've checked publish settings, and doing a URL inspection.

Comment: FYI - when I type www.example.com/robots.txt is comes up with a 404 error message "The page you have entered does not exist" and then has a link to my main site.